# Laravel Horizon jobs pending not executed in local development running in docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, redis, laravel-horizon

I try to add Laravel Horizon to my app on the local environment via doker to run a queue with Redis. After installation, I can see the Horizon dashboard. But when I try to add processes in the queue I see them in the pending and never execute.

I am not sure I missed something

Here my docker-compose

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./code:/var/www
      - data:/var/run/php
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - app-network

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - data:/.data
    networks:
      - app-network

  queue:
    container_name: queue
    hostname: queue
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - data:/.data
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  data:
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

.env

```
APP_NAME="Laravel"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_QUEUE=queue
REDIS_QUEUE_HOST=queue

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false
```

horizon.php

```
'defaults' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'auto',
            'autoScalingStrategy' => 'time',
            'maxProcesses' => 10,
            'maxTime' => 0,
            'maxJobs' => 0,
            'memory' => 128,
            'tries' => 1,
            'timeout' => 60,
            'nice' => 0,
        ],
    ],

    'environments' => [
        'production' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'maxProcesses' => 10,
                'balanceMaxShift' => 1,
                'balanceCooldown' => 3,
            ],
        ],

        'local' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'autoScalingStrategy' => 'time',
                'maxProcesses' => 10,
                'maxTime' => 0,
                'maxJobs' => 0,
                'memory' => 128,
                'tries' => 1,
                'timeout' => 60,
                'nice' => 0,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

From the above configuration, I run the command

```
php artisan horizon
```

It did not execute and let them in pending, but If I try `php artisan horizon:work` It will process all pending jobs.

Suppose anyone knows how to fix this or have any suggestions. Please share how to fix it.

Comment: Greatings. Could it be that the supervisor didn't start properly or it has the autostart to false? The worker for the queue doesn't seem to be working by default if they're getting stuck in the queue.